# Serving create-react-app build files on express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I want to serve build files of my react app on my other express application. So I copied all the static files inside build folder to public folder inside my express application and I used.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
    res.send()}
    )

app.get("/differentRoute",(req,res)=>{
    res.send()}
    )

app.listen(4000)
```

When I make a get request on http://localhost:4000/ my react page loads perfectly, however when I make the same request on http://localhost:4000/differentRoute, nothing loads, can someone explain me how it works?

Answer (score 0):

When you request `/` it finds the `index.html` file in the public directory, and serves it up using the static handler.

Nothing get ever get to the explicit handler for `/` since the static route always catches it first.

When you request `/differentRoute`, there is no matching file in the public directory so the explicit route for that is triggered. You call `res.send()` with no arguments, which doesn't make sense.

---

If you want to have URL based routing and don't want to use server side rendering, then use the [HashRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter).

If you want to have real paths for the different pages in the app, then use server side rendering (e.g. with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).